# Trying write and read image to SQLite with C++ Builder

Tags: c++, sqlite, c++builder

I'm using:

- C++ Builder (RAD Studio 10.2)
- SQLite 3

Trying to save PNG image to SQLite base and then get it back. I'm reading forums for three days already but can't find a solution.

Here's my code:

**Image Writing Code**

```
AnsiString Insert_data;
UnicodeString Path;
int rc,filesize,rowid;
sqlite3 *db;
sqlite3_stmt *insert_stmt;
sqlite3_blob *blob;

if(OpenDialog1->Execute())
{
    Memo1->Lines->Add(OpenDialog1->FileName);
    Image1->Picture->LoadFromFile(OpenDialog1->FileName);
}
sqlite3_open16(base_name.c_str(), &db);

Path = OpenDialog1->FileName;
TFileStream *f = new TFileStream(Path, fmOpenRead);
filesize = f->Size;
Memo1->Lines->Add("Вес файла : " + (String)filesize);
f->Position = 0;
Insert_data = "INSERT INTO images(id, pic_id, picture_name, data) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);";
rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, Insert_data.c_str(), -1, &insert_stmt, NULL);
if(rc != SQLITE_OK)
{
    Memo1->Lines->Add(sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    sqlite3_close(db);
}
sqlite3_bind_int(insert_stmt, 1, 1);
sqlite3_bind_int(insert_stmt, 2, 1);
Insert_data = OpenDialog1->FileName;
sqlite3_bind_text(insert_stmt, 3, Insert_data.c_str(), -1, 0);
sqlite3_bind_zeroblob(insert_stmt, 4, filesize);
// sqlite3_bind_blob(insert_stmt,4,f, f->Size,SQLITE_STATIC); // That doesn't work too
rc = sqlite3_step(insert_stmt);
if(rc != SQLITE_DONE)
{
    Memo1->Lines->Add("Insert statement didn't work");
    Memo1->Lines->Add(sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    sqlite3_close(db);
    return;
}
sqlite3_reset(insert_stmt);

rowid = sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(db);

rc = sqlite3_blob_open(db, "main", "images", "data", rowid, 1, &blob);
if(rc != SQLITE_OK)
{
    Memo1->Lines->Add(sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    sqlite3_close(db);
    return;
}
Memo1->Lines->Add("size of BLOB : " + (String)sqlite3_blob_bytes(blob));


rc = sqlite3_blob_write(blob, f, f->Size, 0);
if(rc != SQLITE_OK)
{
    Memo1->Lines->Add("Error write " + IntToStr(error));
    Memo1->Lines->Add(sqlite3_errmsg(db));
}
rc = sqlite3_blob_close( blob ); 
if(rc != SQLITE_OK)
{
    Memo1->Lines->Add("Error close " + IntToStr(error));
    Memo1->Lines->Add(sqlite3_errmsg(db));
}
```

**Image Reading Code**

```
sqlite3 *db; 
sqlite3_blob *data; 
int rc, bytes; 
int error = -100;

sqlite3_open("game_data",&db); 
rc = sqlite3_blob_open(db,"main","images","data",1,0,&data); 
if(rc != SQLITE_OK)
{
    Memo1->Lines->Add(sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    sqlite3_close(db);
    return;
}

bytes = sqlite3_blob_bytes(data); 
char *zBlob = (char *) malloc(bytes); 
error = sqlite3_blob_read(data,zBlob,bytes,0); 
if(error != SQLITE_OK)
{
    Memo1->Lines->Add("Error open " + IntToStr(error));
    Memo1->Lines->Add(sqlite3_errmsg(db));
}

TMemoryStream *ms = new TMemoryStream(); 
ms->Write(zBlob, bytes);
ms->Position = 0;

Memo1->Lines->Add("read: " + IntToStr(bytes));
//Image1->Picture->LoadFromStream(ms); // error
ms->SaveToFile("123.png");

sqlite3_close(db);
//delete []ms;
```

It seems to be written and read, the size in bytes is the same, but the resulting 123.png file is not read as a picture. Something is lost somewhere, I can’t understand what the problem is.

Comment: DId you try to debug your code? If not, please try debugging your code.

Comment: Please confirm that the mixing of APIs has nothing to do with this. For example, `sqlite3_open16` for writing and `sqlite3_open` for reading or any other APIs conflict that has implications other than performance.

Comment: @Azeem `sqlite3_open16()` just expects the filename to be encoded in UTF-16 instead of the UTF-8 of the other open functions. (And if it creates a database, sets the internal encoding to UTF-16 too, but sqlite will convert between it and UTF-8 on demand)

Comment: @Shawn: Thank you! So, the subsequent API calls would have these conversions internally if needed, is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is in this line:

```
rc = sqlite3_blob_write(blob, f, f->Size, 0);
```

where f is a `TFileStream *`. SQLite expects a pointer to a memory buffer to copy bytes from, so you are effectively copying the contents of your `TFileStream` object instead of the file contents. I think you should read the `TFileStream` entirely into a memory buffer first, and pass a pointer to *that* to `sqlite3_write_blob`.

Comment: thanks a lot! This works:  
`char *vchrgBuf;`  
`vchrgBuf = (char *) malloc(f->Size);`  
`f->Read(vchrgBuf,f->Size);`  
`rc = sqlite3_blob_write(blob, vchrgBuf, f->Size, 0);`